# How can I return the download URL of an image uploaded to firebase storage

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I want to upload an image to firebase (which is working), then return the download URL of the image and store it as a string.

Here is my code:

```js
uploadImage = async (uri, imageName) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();

    firebase.storage().ref().child(imageName).put(blob)
      .then(snap => {
        return snap.ref.getDownloadURL();
      })
      .then(downloadURL => {
        return downloadURL;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`An error occurred while uploading the file.\n\n${error}`);
      });
  }
```

The image uploads to firebase storage just fine. At the moment it just shows this when I try write the URL of the uploaded image to the database:
https://ibb.co/WHHHxBY

Here is the block of code where I create the user record:

```js
  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    .then(userCredentials => {
      let imageUrl = '';

      let db = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userCredentials.user.uid);

      if (this.state.image) {
        imageUrl = this.uploadImage(this.state.image.uri, `images/user-${userCredentials.user.uid}`);
      }

      db.set({
        email: this.state.email,
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
        username: this.state.username
      });

      return userCredentials.user.updateProfile({
        displayName: this.state.username
      });
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }));
```

Comment: "when I try write it to the database" -> how are you writing to the DB? Can you share the corresponding code?

Comment: I've written an answer, see below. However I don't understand how you can get the result shown in your image https://ibb.co/WHHHxBY with your code: how do you get the two subnodes `_40`and `_65`? They were there before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `uploadImage` function, you are chaining the promises but you don't return the chain. You should adapt it as follows:

```
uploadImage = async (uri, imageName) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();

    return firebase.storage().ref().child(imageName).put(blob)  // <-- Here return the chain
      .then(snap => {
        return snap.ref.getDownloadURL();
      })
      .then(downloadURL => {
        return downloadURL;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`An error occurred while uploading the file.\n\n${error}`);
      });
  }
```

However, you could transform this code in `async/await` "style", as follows:

```
uploadImage = async (uri, imageName) => {

    try {
        const response = await fetch(uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();

        const snap = await firebase.storage().ref().child(imageName).put(blob);

        const downloadURL = await snap.ref.getDownloadURL();

        return downloadURL;

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        throw e;
    }

}
```

Then, since this `uploadImage` function is asynchronous you should adapt the way you call it. I suggest to modify the other part of your code as follows:

```
try {
     const userCredentials = await firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password);

     let imageUrl = '';

     const db = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userCredentials.user.uid);

     if (this.state.image) {

        imageUrl = await this.uploadImage(this.state.image.uri, `images/user-${userCredentials.user.uid}`);

        await db.set({
            email: this.state.email,
            imageUrl: imageUrl,
            username: this.state.username
          });


          return userCredentials.user.updateProfile({
            displayName: this.state.username
          });

     }
     //You should probably manage the else case

} catch (e) {
     this.setState({ errorMessage: e.message })
}
```

Comment: Hi, I copied over this solution but it still creates the `_40` and `_65` subnodes. Not sure why this happens. Could it be that it doesn't return the correct data to begin with?

Comment: Can you console log the value of `downloadURL`? What do you get?

Comment: See also the update to the answer, which is an adaptation of the code used to create the user record.

Comment: FYI I've just tried all the code of my answer and it works correctly. In particular no `_40`and `_65`subnodes but the correct downloadUrl!

Comment: Logging the URL showed the correct one, but still didn't write the correct value to the database. After updating the other part of my code as you had shown, it solved the problem. Apologies for the late reply and thank you for improving my code quality and solving my issues!